# How do I get the xbox live patch? For more maps and hero assault?

Tags: xbox-360, star-wars-battlefront-2

I have been reading in [various places](http://battlefront.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_Assault) that the Hero Assault mode in Battlefront 2 (available by default only on the Mos Eisley map) is available on more maps with an xbox live patch.

I've been trying to figure out how on earth to get this patch, and I can't figure it out. I'm playing on a 360, and I'm a little worried it just doesn't really apply.

I want to play Hero Assault on more maps!

Comment: Sounds more like a DLC than a patch.  did you look on your game's page to see if there was any?

Comment: Well, the game doesn't really have a page. Unless you're including [the wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battlefront_II)? They have a section *discussing* the dlc, but don't really give any directions about how to access it. Do I have to get it through the game's menus?

Comment: Try inserting the disk,  dashboard, highlight disk press "X".